# Going on a new line when the array reaches a number higher than x

Tags: javascript, arrays

The issue is as followed: i'm trying to make a piece of code that will print all the elements of an array until it reaches an number higher than 30 lets say. When it does reach that number, the code should start on a new line.
For example, i have the array:

```
[5, 34, 8, 31, 7, 5, 4, 39, 9, 10, 11, 32, 14];
```

When the code is finished, it should print something like this:

```
5, 34
8, 31
7, 5, 4, 39
9, 10, 11, 32
14
```

All i've been able to do so far is:

```
var array1 = [5, 34, 8, 31, 7, 5, 4, 39, 9, 10, 11, 32, 14];
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){

}
```

I have no idea how would i continue from here. I've tried different stuff that came through my mind, but nothing worked. Could someone explain? I'm not here just for the solving, but more for the explanation.

Thank you.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: A `counter` variable and an `if` within the loop, which starts a new line once counter is a multiple of 30, in pseudocode: `if (counter % 30 == 0) print "\n";`.

Comment: @Nate Anderson javascript. sorry for forgetting to mention this

Comment: when are you wanting to inject a new line? when you have iterated over 30 times or when when the current number is greater than 30?

Comment: @Nate Anderson  when the current number is greater than 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are writing to the console:

```
var array1 = [5, 34, 8, 31, 7, 5, 4, 39, 9, 10, 11, 32, 14];

var value = '';
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    var number = array1[i];
    value += value.length > 0 ? ',' + number : number;
    if (number > 30) {
        console.log(value);
        value = '';
     }
}
console.log(value);
```

this will print to the console this result:

```
 5,34
 8,31
 7,5,4,39
 9,10,11,32
 14
```

`value` is appended to within every iteration of the loop. If the current number is over 30 then `value` is written to the console. After `value` is written to the console it is cleared.

Comment: Is printing wrong. It should of printed on the first line: 5, 34 | second line: 8, 31 | third line:  7, 5, 4, 39 and so on.

Comment: Edited to reflect desired result

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want :

```
    function printArray(arr){
          for(var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if( arr[i] > 30){
              console.log('\n');
            }
            console.log(arr[i]);
        }

        printArray([5, 34, 8, 31, 7, 5, 4, 39, 9, 10, 11, 32, 14]);
```